# await in different positions yielding different results

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm trying to hide the latency of some code that does calculations.

Examples below.
In the first case below, I get the expected answer:

```
async function calculateStuff(thing) {
    //do stuff here
    return {"a": a, "b": b, "c": c};
}
const data = await calculateStuff(obj); //takes a while
const first = data["a"] //valid data
const second = data["b"] //valid data
const third = data["c"] //valid data
```

I'd like to hide the latency of calculateStuff by doing either of the following, but both methods have my variables become undefined instead:

```
async function calculateStuff(thing) {
    //do stuff here
    return {"a": a, "b": b, "c": c};
}
data = calculateStuff(obj); //takes a while
//...other calculations here...
await data;
const first = data["a"] //undefined
const second = data["b"] //undefined
const third = data["c"] //undefined
```

Likewise:

```
async function calculateStuff(thing) {
    //do stuff here
    return {"a": a, "b": b, "c": c};
}
data = calculateStuff(obj); //takes a while
//...other calculations here...
const first = await data["a"] //undefined
const second = await data["b"] //undefined
const third = await data["c"] //undefined
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You want parallelism, which I don't think that you can get with just `async`-`await`.

Comment: What is `//do stuff here` and `//...other calculations here...`? Are these actually asynchronous things?

Comment: In `const data = await calculateStuff(obj);`, `data` is the result object (fulfillment value of the promise). In `const data = calculateStuff(obj);`, `data` is a promise object, which doesn't have `["a"]`/`["b"]`/`["c"]` properties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An async function will return a Promise. Calling `await myAsyncFunction()`, will *return* the value of the Promise once the Promise is fulfilled. Note the `return` in the previous statement. **It does not change the pointer in place.**

E.g. calling `await data` does not change `data`.

You can get the output you expect by calling `data = await data`.

```js
async function test()
{
  return {a: 1, b: 2};
}

async function run()
{
  let data = test();
  data = await data;
  console.log("A", data.a);
}

run();
```

You can also use `.then()`.

```js
async function test()
{
  return {a: 1, b: 2};
}

async function run()
{
  let data = test();
  data.then((out) => {
    console.log("A", out.a);
  });
}

run();
```

Comment: Will this really run `test()` in parallel with other code?

Comment: @md2perpe - I don't really expect it to be parallel (I don't think it's parallel, or even a different thread). A lot of the latency in my calculation is due to having to call a couple of APIs. And just didn't want other calculations to be bogged down by waiting for a response. While my calc is waiting for a response, I was hoping to do other useful work. So I'm hoping to hide network latency, but not hoping to hide computational latency.